# Need to add a constructor to my derived class that access a private member variable from the base class

Tags: c++

I have to type in below the missing constructor for class Child that will initialize all member variables when object child{1,2} is instantiated from the class in the main program.

I know this->b = b should work, however, I have problems when trying to set the a value equal to the private member int a in class Parent. Sorry if my directions aren't too clear.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent
{
private:
  int a {0};
public:
  Parent() = default;
  Parent(int a) {this->a = a;}
  int getA()
  { return a; }
};

class Child : public Parent 
{
private:
  int b {0};
public:
  Child() = default;
  //missing constructor
  int getB()
  { return b; }
};


int main()
{
  Child child{1,2};
  int holdA = child.getA();
  int holdB = child.getB();
  cout << "Int a is " << holdA << " and Int b is " << holdB << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I have problems when trying to set the a value equal to the private member int a in class Parent."* -- One thing I'd do is look at the code for a line like `this->a = a;`. How can you get to that line from your constructor?

Comment: Im running into the same issues. I would make a public however I am not allowed to modify the code, only the line with //missing constructor

Comment: This is also an old homework problem I got wrong I am trying to solve before finals.

Comment: If you want to construct a `Child` instance with two arguments, just write such a constructor.
What is the reason for not doing so?

Comment: My constructor as of now says Child(int a, int b) {this->a = a; this->b = b;} however I cannot access a because it is private. I am only allowed to change the constructor. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Call constructor of `Parent` from constructor of `Child` : `Child(int a,int b) : Parent(a), b(b) {}`

Comment: That was it! Thank you. May I ask, is there any way to write it in the format Child(int a, int b) {*constructor body here*}. It makes more sense to me that way. If not, thank you and I will learn how to write it like this.

Comment: `Parent::a` is private, and no way to change it is provided.
So, there is no way to change `Parent::a` value after `Parent` constructed.
What we can do is only pass the initial value to provided constructor `Panert::Parent(int)`.

Comment: There is an [example at cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Example).

Comment: @user18733091 The variable being *private* signals that derived classes should not even assume that the variable exists, so assigning a value to it in the derived class makes no sense at all. (Also, you should study the difference between initialization and assignment, which is very important in C++.)